# Error in scikit-learn ColumnTransformer: Mismatched Input Array Dimensions during Data Transformation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I'm encountering an error while using scikit-learn's ColumnTransformer for data transformation. The error message states "all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly." This occurs during the execution of my data ingestion and transformation pipeline. The input array sizes along dimension 0 are inconsistent (1064 and 1070) when trying to concatenate them. This issue arises from line 110 of the data_transformation.py script. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this mismatched input array dimensions error.

Data_ingestion.py

```
import os
import sys
from exception import CustomException
from logger import logging
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dataclasses import dataclass

from components.data_transformation import DataTransformation
from components.data_transformation import DataTransformationConfig

from components.model_trainer import ModelTrainerConfig
from components.model_trainer import ModelTrainer

@dataclass
class DataIngestionConfig:
    train_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"train.csv")
    test_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"test.csv")
    raw_data_path: str=os.path.join('artifacts',"data.csv")

class DataIngestion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ingestion_config=DataIngestionConfig()

    def initiate_data_ingestion(self):
        logging.info("Entered the data ingestion method or component")
        try:
            df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\Notebook\Medical cost.csv')
            logging.info('Read the dataset as dataframe')

            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path),exist_ok=True)

            df.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.raw_data_path,index=False,header=True)

            logging.info("Train test split initiated")
            train_set,test_set=train_test_split(df,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

            train_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path,index=False,header=True)

            test_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.test_data_path,index=False,header=True)

            logging.info("Ingestion of the data is completed")

            return(
                self.ingestion_config.train_data_path,
                self.ingestion_config.test_data_path

            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e,sys)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=DataIngestion()
    train_data,test_data=obj.initiate_data_ingestion()

    data_transformation=DataTransformation()
    train_arr,test_arr,_=data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation(train_data,test_data)

    modeltrainer=ModelTrainer()
    print(modeltrainer.initiate_model_trainer(train_arr,test_arr))
```

Data_transformation.py

```
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass

import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder,StandardScaler

from exception import CustomException
from logger import logging
import os

from utils import save_object

@dataclass
class DataTransformationConfig:
    preprocessor_obj_file_path=os.path.join('artifacts',"proprocessor.pkl")

def remove_outliers(data, columns, z_threshold=3):
    for column in columns:
        z_scores = np.abs(stats.zscore(data[column]))
        data = data[z_scores < z_threshold]
        data = data[data['bmi'] < 47]  # Filtering based on "bmi" column
    return data

class DataTransformation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_transformation_config=DataTransformationConfig()

    def get_data_transformer_object(self):
        '''
        This function si responsible for data trnasformation
        
        '''
        try:
            numerical_columns = ["age", "bmi"]
            categorical_columns = [
                "sex",
                "children",
                "smoker",
                "region"

            ]

            num_pipeline= Pipeline(
                steps=[
                ("outlier_remover", FunctionTransformer(remove_outliers, kw_args={"columns": numerical_columns, "z_threshold": 3})),
                ("imputer",SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
                ("scaler",StandardScaler())

                ]
            )

            cat_pipeline=Pipeline(

                steps=[
                ("imputer",SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
                ("one_hot_encoder",OneHotEncoder()),
                ]

            )

            logging.info(f"Categorical columns: {categorical_columns}")
            logging.info(f"Numerical columns: {numerical_columns}")

            preprocessor=ColumnTransformer(
                [
                ("num_pipeline",num_pipeline,numerical_columns),
                ("cat_pipelines",cat_pipeline,categorical_columns)

                ]


            )

            return preprocessor
        
        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e,sys)
        
    def initiate_data_transformation(self,train_path,test_path):

        try:
            train_df=pd.read_csv(train_path)
            test_df=pd.read_csv(test_path)

            logging.info("Read train and test data completed")

            logging.info("Obtaining preprocessing object")

            preprocessing_obj=self.get_data_transformer_object()

            target_column_name="charges"
            numerical_columns = ["age", "bmi"]

            input_feature_train_df=train_df.drop(columns=[target_column_name],axis=1)
            target_feature_train_df=train_df[target_column_name]

            input_feature_test_df=test_df.drop(columns=[target_column_name],axis=1)
            target_feature_test_df=test_df[target_column_name]

            logging.info(
                f"Applying preprocessing object on training dataframe and testing dataframe."
            )

            input_feature_train_arr=preprocessing_obj.fit_transform(input_feature_train_df)
            input_feature_test_arr=preprocessing_obj.transform(input_feature_test_df)

            train_arr = np.c_[
                input_feature_train_arr, np.array(target_feature_train_df)
            ]
            test_arr = np.c_[input_feature_test_arr, np.array(target_feature_test_df)]

            logging.info(f"Saved preprocessing object.")

            save_object(

                file_path=self.data_transformation_config.preprocessor_obj_file_path,
                obj=preprocessing_obj

            )

            return (
                train_arr,
                test_arr,
                self.data_transformation_config.preprocessor_obj_file_path,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e,sys)
```

I attempted to use scikit-learn's ColumnTransformer for data transformation in my pipeline. I expected the transformation to concatenate the input arrays seamlessly. However, I encountered an error stating that the input array dimensions were mismatched (1064 vs 1070) along dimension 0. This occurred while executing the data_transformation.py script. I'm looking for a solution to address this dimension mismatch issue and successfully perform the data transformation.

```
(C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial) C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions>python src/components/data_ingestion.py
Mean Squared Error (MSE) on test set: 21466534.697689235
Mean Absolute Error (MAE) on test set: 2508.0220646012804
R-squared (R2) on test set: 0.8617281153190824
None

(C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial) C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions>python src/components/data_ingestion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\medical_cost_predictions\src\components\data_transformation.py", line 110, in initiate_data_transformation
    input_feature_train_arr=preprocessing_obj.fit_transform(input_feature_train_df)
  File "C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 767, in fit_transform
    return self._hstack(list(Xs))
  File "C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 892, in _hstack
    return np.hstack(Xs)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in hstack
  File "C:\Users\pj\Desktop\End to End Project\Medical_Cost_Predictions\medicial\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 370, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1, dtype=dtype, casting=casting)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1064 and the array at index 1 has size 1070

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/components/data_ingestion.py", line 58, in <module>
    train_arr,test_arr,_=data_transformation.initiate_data_transformation(train_data,test_data)
  File "c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\medical_cost_predictions\src\components\data_transformation.py", line 133, in initiate_data_transformation
    raise CustomException(e,sys)
exception.CustomException: Error occured in python script name [c:\users\pj\desktop\end to end project\medical_cost_predictions\src\components\data_transformation.py] line number [110] error message[all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1064 and the array at index 1 has size 1070]
```

What I've Tried:

I've investigated the issue and tried different approaches, but I'm still unable to resolve it. I've also ensured that both input arrays have the same number of rows, but the error persists. Here is the GitHub repository containing the data and the relevant code for reference: https://github.com/pras-ops/Medical_Cost_Predictions

Comment: You should try to reduce code clutter. Using a toy dataset (say from sklearn) and just your column transformer you can recreate the issue. See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your numerical pipeline removes (outlier) rows, but the categorical pipeline does not (nor do you remove corresponding rows from y...).

You can find many questions here and at datascience.SE about getting outliers removed inside sklearn pipelines. It's not very straightforward, for exactly the reason you've run into, but it's possible.